# Is this possible to get a box like this?

Tags: tcolorbox

My requirement is need to get some text surrounded by a box like:

[image]

I tried with:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[drop shadow west,
enhanced,colback=white,colframe=black!10]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

But the output not like that what I need. Please advise...

Suggestion gave by `Ignasi` (thanks a lot) was working fine in `PDFLaTeX` and `XeLaTeX`, but I'm in need of using `LaTeX -> dvips -> Ps2PDF`, please advise for this...

Comment: The `dvips` driver have only limited fadings capability. They are supported but as the documentation clearly states "*the results will not be as good as with a driver producing pdf as output*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start looking at `vignette` tcolorbox library which allows to do inner fadings.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, colback=white, frame hidden,
underlay vignette={draw method=clipped, size=3mm, semi fade in=gray, east size=1.5mm, south size=1mm}]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update: Different fadings**

It's possible to decide the color and fading style for every side of the box.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, colback=white, frame hidden,
underlay vignette={draw method=clipped, size=3mm, semi fade in=gray, east size=1.5mm, south size=1mm}]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{tcolorbox}

%semi fade in=gray, fixes fading for all four sides
%but `south style` and `east style` apply a particular fading
%
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, colback=white, frame hidden,
underlay vignette={draw method=clipped, size=3mm, semi fade in=gray, east size=1.5mm, south size=1mm, south style={gray!10!white, path fading=east},
east style={gray!10!white, path fading=south}}]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick suggestion, but I could get solid rules at all sides? I just copied your code and tried, is there anything I need to do further? Note that I'm using MikTeX 2.9 in Windows7, please advise...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Your picture doesn't show "solid rules at all sides", Do you want solid rules and inner fuzzi shadow?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I need the rules with inner fuzzi shadows, but if I execute your suggested code, I got the solid rules only, I didn't get the output what you pasted in your answer part, please advise if any mistake I did? Hope this is clear...

Comment: Please advise, should I include any `library`? I am using MikTeX 2.9 `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140) (preloaded format=latex 2021.1.19)` and `LaTeX`, `dvips` and `ps2pdf`

Comment: yes, my assumption is correct, it works well in PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX, but when using `dvips` and `ps2pdf` all the rules are changed to solid one? Please advise how can I fix the same in `LaTeX -> dvips -> ps2pdf`? Please....

Comment: @MadyYuvi About the box rule, delete `frame hidden` option. About the problem with `dvips` I cannot help you. Why do you need this way?

Comment: Thanks, will do as per you suggested, if I go with `PS2PDF`, I can able to make the PDF with specific `Printer` setting like `Sheridan`, etc.by using `Acrobat Distiller`, if I go with direct PDF, I can't, that's why I preferred `dvips`...

Comment: Is this possible to fix the shade at right side and bottom of the box more lighter than the top and left side? Please advise... Sorry for the trouble...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Take a look at updated version. I hope it helps you.

Comment: You really one of great in `tcolorbox`...Thanks a lot...